# How to max out level, and what is it?

Tags: dex

A [screenshot](https://steamcommunity.com/app/269650/discussions/0/481115363870523926/#c481115363873639302) shows that at least LV 18.3 is possible, needing ~10K more EXP for LV 19, and they're missing a few things, about 3000 EXP from my estimate, but is it possible to get more?

Can enemies drop datachips / data-cubes for EXP / Skill Points or are all data-boosting consumables from container loot / shops?